# Is it possible to communicate with smartcard from QML?

Tags: qml, nfc, smartcard

I want to know if it's possible for QML (because it's used in a lot of mobile OSes) to interact with a nfc smartcard i.e. credit card, transit pass, passport etc. or with C++ code also used in developing QML apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Qt NFC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnfc-index.html) API, but it's only supported on BlackBerry devices. However, QML can be easily extended using C++, so if you can do it in C++, you can basically do it in QML. All you have to do is create appropriate bindings, which is not that hard.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that in C++?

Comment: @user2563892 You mean extend QML or access NFC functionality?

Comment: Access NFC functionality

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's too broad to cover. You should consult dev docs for relevant platforms.

Comment: So, it's basically imposible. I want to develop for Ubuntu Touch (doesn't have anything on NFC yet). I'll just drop it then.